# Running expression predicate on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, jsonpath

I am creating list of JObject like below. I would like to search the collection using query expression. In the sample code below I am using Jsonpath query to find all position object which is of type Buy (enum Buy has int value of 1 )

```
List<JObject> list = new List<JObject>();
list.Add(JObject.FromObject(new Position() { PositionType = PositionType.Buy, Investment = new Investment() { InvestmentCode = "AAPL" } }));
list.Add(JObject.FromObject(new Position() { PositionType = PositionType.Sell, Investment = new Investment() { InvestmentCode = "AAPL" } }));

var x = list.Find(j =>
{
    JToken token =  j.SelectToken("$[?(@.PositionType == 1)]");
    return token != null;
});
```

The SelectToken method returns null within the predicate. I am not sure if I am using a right method. Is there a way a predicate can be evaluated on the object?

Comment: `var x = list.Find(j => j.SelectToken("$[?(@.PositionType == 1)]"));` that is what the line should be, but, you probably should do something more like `list.Where(j => j["PositionType"] != null).First(j => j["PositionType"] == 1)`

Comment: If you have it as a .NET type already, why not just do a LINQ query on the collection directly? Why convert it to a JObject first?

Comment: I provided above sample for an example. My intention is to build a dynamic Json object store and have caller provide filter using json path. The library would have no knowledge of the type.

Answer (score 1):

It's not well explained by the [`SelectTokens()` documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) or the [JSONPath standard](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), but the `[?(script)]` operator is *arguably* defined to be for conditional selection of **child objects**.   This is because the `[?()]` operator is actually a combination of the *script operator* nested inside the *child/subscript operator*.  From the [standard](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/):

> Here is a complete overview and a side by side comparison of the JSONPath syntax elements with its XPath counterparts.
>
> ```
> XPath    JSONPath    Description 
> /        . or []     child operator 
> []       []          subscript operator. XPath uses it to iterate over element collections and for predicates. In Javascript and JSON it is the native array operator. 
> []       ?()         applies a filter (script) expression. 
> n/a      ()          script expression, using the underlying script engine.
> ```

The only examples the standard shows of the `[?()]` operator is in matching properties of objects inside arrays, and returning those objects.

Thus if I do `SelectTokens()` on `[{"PositionType": 1}]` using `"$[?(@.PositionType == 1)]"` then one object is returned, but doing it on `{"PositionType": 1}` (as you are trying to do inside your `Find()` predicate) returns nothing.

Json.NET is not entirely idiosyncratic in its interpretation of the standard.  Here are the results of trying to match `{"PositionType": 1}` against `"$[?(@.PositionType == 1)]"` and `$..[?(@.PositionType == 1)]` using various JSONPath parsers:

- http://www.jsonquerytool.com/ - neither matches.
- http://jsonpath.com/ - neither matches.
- http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

  - "Jayway": - both match.
  - "Gatling" - `"$[?(@.PositionType == 1)]"` matches, `$..[?(@.PositionType == 1)]` errors.  (Update: with [Gatling](https://github.com/gatling/jsonpath) version 0.6.7, both match.)
  - "Nebhale" - both error.
  - "Goessner" - neither matches.

You could [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) about Json.NET's behavior, but given the inconsistency between implementations it might not get addressed.  The JSONPath standard simply may not be well-defined and stable enough for your needs as compared to XPath at this point.

See also [Newtonsoft JSON SelectToken to get data from multiple parts of JSON document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073095/newtonsoft-json-selecttoken-to-get-data-from-multiple-parts-of-json-document) and [How to select JToken based on multiple name candidates in JSONPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641824/how-to-select-jtoken-based-on-multiple-name-candidates-in-jsonpath).

Comment: Jayway's webapp doesn't use an up-to-date Gatling JsonPath version (0.6.4, released more than one year ago). I tested with latest 0.6.7 and both expressions match properly.